# Content loss in Drupal related with field_attach_update

Tags: nodes, entities, database

Drupal field_attach_update seems to be the cause of a content loss in my application.

This function is used to save a node field instead of the whole node but if it is not used properly it can produce a content loss.

Normally, in Drupal the common way to save a node is using node_save function but this function will save all node fields and this consumes more resources.

Problem is node_save uses db_transaction function to create a db transaction and avoid concurrent accesses to the database. field_attach_update does not use db_transaction so, for me the proper way to update a field would be like this:

```
$transaction = db_transaction();
try {
    $node = node_load(1); // where 1 is the nid you want to change
    $update_node = new stdClass();
    $update_node->nid = $node->nid;
    $update_node->vid = $node->vid;
    $update_node->type = $node->type;
    $update_node->field_FIELD_NAME['und'][0]['value'] = VALUE_YOU_WANT_TO_CHANGE;
    field_attach_update('node', $update_node);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

What do you think? Do you agree with this?

Comment: Field storage is pluggable, so a db transaction won't always be possible - I'd imagine that's the general reason it hasn't been implemented. I'd agree that a transaction would be wise here if your storage is in the database though, and yes, your implementation looks sound